# Global Filter registering error on MVC 3 RC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a mvc 3 web app, but my shared web hosting company supports MVC 2 only.
So I deploy mvc 3 related dlls too, and it had worked well on the server till it was mvc 3 beta.

Yesterday, I upgraded my pc environment to the mvc 3 RC and rebuilt my web app. The app works well on my local pc, but when i deploy and run on the hosting server, it makes an error.

```
[MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void System.Web.Mvc.GlobalFilterCollection.Add(System.Object)'.]
Myweb.MvcApplication.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters) in c:\my\Global.asax.cs:18
Myweb.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in c:\my\Global.asax.cs:36
```

As you see, when i try to register global filter in global.asax, it says it can't find Mvc.GlobalFilterCollection.Add(object) method.

If i do not register any global filter, the whole web works well on the hosting server.

How can I solve this error?

edit:
It seems that the mvc3 beta is registered in the GAC of the hosting server. They said it's not, but i checked the location of the referenced System.Web.Mvc.dll in my app.

Comment: Can you list which DLLs you deployed to the server? In MVC 3 there are now several DLLs that need to be deployed, including System.Web.WebPages as well as several others. Pretty much everything that's not in the .NET Framework itself will need to be deployed to the bin directory on the hoster.

Comment: @Eilon, I had deployed these things. [System.Web.Mvc (ver.3), Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll, System.Web.Helpers, System.Web.Razor, System.Web.WebPages, System.Web.WebPages.Razor].

Comment: @Eilon, but even after deleted those dlls above, my MVC 3 with Razor based web is running. I wondered these are already installed in the server GAC, but tech support person said it's not. Should the application pool be recycled to take effect of the removed dlls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your description I looks like you have a mksmatch between the version of MVC 3 that you are using on your machine and the version that's uploaded to your server. We changed the parameters for `GlobalFilterCollection.Add` and it looks like you are compiling your application on your PC using MVC 3 RC, however you are deploying it to a sever that has MVC 3 Beta. Please make sure that the version of System.Web.Mvc.dll is the right one on your sever.

Edit: To confirm Eilon's comment, if MVC 3 Beta is installed into the GAC then it will always win, even if you have the RC version in your app's bin folder.

Comment: Thnx marcind. Actually I already had copied rc version to the sever. So, I printed log in the global.asax to see the System.Web.Mvc.dll's location, and found out it is in GAC_MSIL folder !. I had got confirmed from the tech support team of the hosing company that mvc3 is not in their GAC, but it seems that beta version is.

Comment: @marcind, then is there a way to force to reference the RC version System.Web.Mvc.dll in the /bin directory instead of beta version dll in GAC?  Can 'bindingRedirect' work?

Comment: @tk the GAC will always win in this scenario because the DLLs have the same version.

Comment: Is there some solution to this problem? Modifying the RC dll in some way so that it has precedence over the beta dll in the GAC?

Comment: No. The only solution is to remove the beta dll from the gac

Comment: Considering that MVC 3 RC is open source, what would need to be changed in the source fix this? Would changing the dll's version to a different number fix this?

Comment: Sure you could compile MVC yourself with version 3.0.1. But ultimately the issue is with the hoster having installed beta in the gac.